# I cannot upload large (> 2GB) files to the Google Cloud Storage web UI

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have been using the `Google Cloud Storage Manager` link on the [Google APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?#%3astorage) in order to upload my files.

This works great for most files: 1KB, 10KB, 1MB, 10MB, 100MB. However yesterday I could not upload a 3GB file. Any idea what is wrong?

What is the best way to upload large files to Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Another way to upload large files can be seen [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137039/how-do-i-upload-a-file-size-greater-than-30mb-to-google-cloud-storage-with-gsuti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web UI only supports uploads smaller than 2^32 bytes (4 GigaBytes). I believe this is a javascript limitation.

If you need to transfer many or large files consider using [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil):

1. GSUtil uploads and downloads any size file.
2. GSUtil [resumes uploads](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/developer-guide#resumable) and [resumes downloads](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#range) that fail part way through.
3. GSUtil calculates the [MD5 checksum](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#contentmd5) to verify the contents of each file transferred correctly.
4. GSUtil can upload and download many files at the same time.

   - `gsutil -m cp /path/to/*thousands-of-files* gs://my-bucket/*`

Comment: gsutil is good, but web interface can handle files > 2GB, and note that 2^32 is 4GB, not 2.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, the accepted answer is not correct - maybe it was but something has changed.

I just uploaded a file of size 2.2GB to GCS using the web interface on Chrome 42 on Windows 8.1.

I would also point out that the question is about files > 2GB, and the answer mentions 2GB, but gets that from 2^32, which is 4GB, not 2.  So maybe the limit really is 2^32 (4GB) - I haven't tried anything that big.

(It is still a good idea to use gsutil for large files.)