# how do I split a large csv.gz file in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I get this error when trying to load a table in Google BQ:

> Input CSV files are not splittable and at least one of the files is
>   larger than the maximum allowed size. Size is: 56659381010. Max
>   allowed size is: 4294967296.

Is there a way to split the file using gsutil or something like that without having to upload everything again?

Comment: Does this help in any way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784757/error-loading-large-csv-into-google-bigquery

Comment: instead of splitting the compressed file, uncompress it - and BigQuery will be able to ingest it easily. to uncompress, go through GCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest compressed CSV file you can load into BigQuery is [4 gigabytes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy). GCS unfortunately does not provide a way to decompress a compressed file, nor does it provide a way to split a compressed file. GZip'd files can't be arbitrarily split up and reassembled in the way you could a tar file.

I imagine your best bet would likely be to spin up a GCE instance in the same region as your GCS bucket, download your object to that instance (which should be pretty fast, given that it's only a few dozen gigabytes), decompress the object (which will be slower), break that CSV file into a bunch of smaller ones (the linux `split` command is useful for this), and then upload the objects back up to GCS.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and this is how I dealt with it:

First, spin up a Google Compute Engine VM instance.
https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

Then install the gsutil commands and then go through the authentication process.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install

Once you have verified that the gcloud, gsutil, and bq commands are working then save a snapshot of the disk as snapshot-1 and then delete this VM.

---

On your **local machine**, run this command to create a new disk. This disk is used for the VM so that you have enough space to download and unzip the large file.

```
gcloud compute disks create disk-2017-11-30 --source-snapshot snapshot-1 --size=100GB
```

Again on your local machine, run this command to create a new VM instance that uses this disk. I use the --preemptible flag to save some cost.

```
gcloud compute instances create loader-2017-11-30 --disk name=disk-2017-11-30,boot=yes --preemptible
```

---

Now you can SSH into your instance and then run these commands on the **remote machine**.

First, copy the file from cloud storage to the VM

```
gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/2017/11/20171130.gz .
```

Then unzip the file. In my case, for ~4GB file, it took about 17 minutes to complete this step:

```
gunzip 20171130.gz
```

Once unzipped, you can either run the bq load command to load it into BigQuery but I found that for my file size (~70 GB unzipped), that operation would take about 4 hours. Instead, I uploaded the unzipped file back to Cloud Storage

```
gsutil cp 20171130 gs://am-alphahat-regional/unzipped/20171130.csv
```

---

Now that the file is back on cloud storage, you can run this command to delete the VM.

```
gcloud compute instances delete loader-2017-11-30
```

Theoretically, the associated disk should also have been deleted, but I found that the disk was still there and I needed to delete it with an additional command

```
gcloud compute disks delete disk-2017-11-30
```

---

Now finally, you should be able to run the bq load command or you can load the data from the console.

Comment: You can use streaming unzip: `gsutil cp gs://bucket/file.csv.gz - | gunzip | gsutil cp - gs://bucket/file.csv`, this way it doesn't require any local disks to store the data

Comment: Thank you @Poma thats a great command to do it on the fly