# Google Cloud Storage Web UI limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, limit

I came across this SO question: [I cannot upload large (> 2GB) files to the Google Cloud Storage web UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530480/i-cannot-upload-large-2gb-files-to-the-google-cloud-storage-web-ui)

wherein it was stated that the upload limit for GCS Web UI upload should be smaller than 2^32 bytes (4 GigaBytes). I just wanted to know if this remains true up to now.

I asked this since there are no provisions on the GCS documentation regarding web UI upload limits.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such limit as of now

Comment: Thank you! Additional inquiry though, since there's no such limit, I'm under the assumption that I should be able to upload large chunks of files via Web UI without encountering any errors? Unless it's network related?

Comment: Yes, but there's still a limit for a maximum size of 5 TB for individual objects stored in GCS.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!